# Salesforce Industry Cloud (E&U) - Contracts object use

Tags: contracts, vlocity, energy-and-utilities, industry-cloud

In Salesforce Energy & Utilities [Data Model](https://sf-zdocs-cdn-prod.zoominsoftware.com/energy.ditamap-enus/a2f622cb-37ae-48f3-a7d4-0bde4e5bdf52/reusables_industries/reusables_global/images/energy___customer_model__20.png), there is the "Contract" object. If Contract Lifecycle Management (CLM) is not used, is there any reason why to use Contracts? It seems to me that it's not that much needed, because information is captured on Order level. Has anyone a reasonable opinion for the above?